# The "right here, right now" sample in "Right Here, Right Now"

Tags: lyrics, history, sample, fatboy-slim

In Fatboy Slim’s [*Right Here, Right Now*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_Here,_Right_Now_(Fatboy_Slim_song)), the lyrics contain repetitions of "right here, right now", spoken by a woman.

This sample seems to be taken from the movie [*Strange Days*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_Days_%28film%29), where Angela Bassett says these words:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3Aeb8yx4_k

This is claimed by both Wikipedia articles ([#Content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_Here,_Right_Now_%28Fatboy_Slim_song%29#Content), [#Production](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_Days_%28film%29#Production)), but they don’t give a source.

Did Fatboy Slim, or another authoritative source, ever confirm that this is a sample taken from the movie? And is there a story behind this (e.g., is it known *why* he chose this sample)?

Comment: He chose the sample because he liked it. We can't give much of a better answer than that

Comment: @ZachSaucier: … unless he wrote it about it, no? (I’m not interested in guesses, only if it’s *known*.)

Comment: I can't find a totally authoritative source, but IMDB and whosampled both support this, as do many other sites on the internet - and I can't find anywhere contradicting it!

Comment: There was a ton of tracks that he himself said in an interview that he did not get permission to sample things. He has stated he doesn't like talking about his earlier samples because of this (probably not wanting to bring light to it). This is probably one of those songs that contains a sample without permission and why you cannot find much official info about it.

Answer (score 11):

Not totally authoritative, but compare for yourself

I did a quick edit/overlay for comparison.

I'd say it's close enough to be sure they are the same.

https://clyp.it/yhomglty#

Short snippet, with 4 repeats of the phrase… in this order…

original record; with movie soundtrack overdubbed; movie on its own; original record

I didn't go to the extreme effort of completely phase-locking it [way too much work, but you can hear a slight phase on the "here" when they're doubled.
The "right now" is time-stretched to fit, though not as tightly as the record.